# Rand() is generating repeated number, I want to be generated unique numbers

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a table by the name of images which is storing the ImageID, images folder path and Images name. For holding 
these images a folder is going to be created automatically while uploading images by The mkdir () function and taking its 
name from rand () function.

problem is whenever I’m using Rand() for naming my images folder it’s repeating. Means the rand() is generating repeated numbers what I should do to be unique? Actually the Image ID is the name of the folder which is primary key and I also need unique values.

Is there any other function to be used to generate unique numbers?

Date and Time function is using : and / so folder name can not accept : and /.

Any way to accomplish this one?

Comment: How you are generating the random number presently?

Comment: Use a [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)

Comment: @user3414693: i m currently generating numbers by rand() which is repeating

Comment: rand() will generate random numbers NOT unique. For unique numbers, you can use UUID or if your logic allows using auto increment number, go for it. (You will have to first create a record in table and then use the newly generated id).

Comment: @Riz:  did google for UUID but i have not found examples with PHP. can i use it with PHP or not?

Comment: he guys i did google and i found uniqid(). is it generating repeated numbers or not

Answer (score 0):

using this you can check if image folder name exist or not, before inserting the name

```
SELECT CONCAT('img',FLOOR(RAND() * 1000000000)) AS image_folder_name
    FROM table
    WHERE image_folder_name NOT IN (SELECT image_folder_column_name FROM table)
    LIMIT 1
```